# Check if date and time is free

Tags: php, sql

so I'm trying to solve out how to check if selected time is free. As example I have record in database:

```
date_from: 2017-06-05
date_till: 2017-07-05
Time_showed: 17:00 - 17:05
```

Time showed means that video begins to play at 17:00 and ends at 17:05.
So now new order is incoming:

```
date_from: 2017-06-12
date_till: 2017-09-05
Time_showed: 17:02 - 17:06
```

So as we see time between 17:02 and 17:06 is taken (17:03-17:05). Any Ideas how to check it with sql and php, so that in this situation it would return an error "Time is taken" ?

And Yeah stackoverflow wasn't the first place wjere I came to ask. Before that I tried to google a lot and solve it on my own... Seems like I'm not tough enough to solve it, lol.

Comment: That's poor table design. You shouldn't have one field for that. start_time , end_time columns. Then you could have a form with two inputs, checking whether start >= or <= end, etc

Comment: You can split them by '-' ?

Comment: Do you have three columns in your table?  Or something different?

Comment: @Degan I have more, like: name,owner_name,id,times_showed...

Comment: As @clearshot66 has explained, your problem is "times_showed".  If you can, change the structure of the database to have two time columns, Showed_Start and Showed_End.  If not, then you should do this into a temp table when you run the query.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can kind of see why you would need the data designed this way but it may be worth your time to see if it could be designed differently. 
However, you came for help so that is what we all should be doing instead of making judgement. We have all worked on DBs that have not been designed in the best way and had to live with it for whatever reason. (Stepping off my soap box..)

So I think you may want to put this as a stored proc that you pass in the dates and the show time and return a true false. 
The conditions you need to check for are:
    Is this during existing hold date period AND --Will assume this period can be null
    Is this during existing hold time. -- will assume this has to be inputted. If all day would have a time like 00:00 - 24:59

I came up with the below script:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables where tables.name like  '#myTable%')
begin 
    drop table #myTable
end;


CREATE TABLE #myTable
(
    date_from date NULL,
    date_till date NULL,
    Time_showed varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO #myTable
VALUES
    ('2017-06-05', '2017-07-05', '17:00 - 17:05'),
    ('2017-06-05', '2017-06-05', '08:00 - 08:05');

--test data
DECLARE 
    @test_from date,
    @test_till as date, 
    @test_time_showed as varchar(20);
--SELECT 
--  @test_from = '2017-06-12', 
--  @test_till = '2017-07-05',
--  @test_time_showed = '17:02 - 17:06';--1
SELECT 
    @test_from = '2017-06-05', 
    @test_till = '2017-06-05',
    @test_time_showed = '08:00 - 08:00';--0
--SELECT 
--  @test_from = '2017-06-05', 
--  @test_till = '2017-06-05',
--  @test_time_showed = '07:59 - 08:00';--0
--SELECT 
--  @test_from = '2017-06-12', 
--  @test_till = '2017-07-05',
--  @test_time_showed = '17:07 - 17:16';--0

--SPLIT 
DECLARE @start_time time = CONVERT(TIME,RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@test_time_showed,0,CHARINDEX('-',@test_time_showed))));--you should turn this into a function (GetStartTime)
DECLARE @end_time time = CONVERT(TIME,LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@test_time_showed,CHARINDEX('-',@test_time_showed) + 1,len(@test_time_showed))));--you should turn this into a function (GetEndTime)

----checking values CAN BE DELETED
--SELECT @start_time,@end_time;

--SELECT  date_from, date_till,
--  CONVERT(TIME,RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Time_showed,0,CHARINDEX('-',Time_showed)))) AS START_T,
--  CONVERT(TIME,LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Time_showed,CHARINDEX('-',Time_showed) + 1,len(Time_showed)))) AS END_T
--FROM #MYTABLE

--VALIDATION
--TODO: You need to add some validation to insure that you are getting the correct data.

--CHECK 
    -- IS 
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT date_from 
                        FROM #myTable 
                        WHERE 
                            --check if any records on file is for any date in span
                            ((date_from BETWEEN @test_from AND @test_till) OR
                            (date_till BETWEEN @test_from AND @test_till) ) AND
                            --if a record is for any date in span, check if times overlap (THE NASTY STUFF)
                            (
                                @start_time > CONVERT(TIME,RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Time_showed,0,CHARINDEX('-',Time_showed))))--you should turn this into a function (GetStartTime)
                                AND 
                                @start_time < CONVERT(TIME,LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Time_showed,CHARINDEX('-',Time_showed) + 1,len(Time_showed))))--you should turn this into a function (GetEndTime)
                            ) OR
                            (
                                @end_time > CONVERT(TIME,RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Time_showed,0,CHARINDEX('-',Time_showed))))--you should turn this into a function (GetStartTime)
                                AND 
                                @end_time < CONVERT(TIME,LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Time_showed,CHARINDEX('-',Time_showed) + 1,len(Time_showed))))--you should turn this into a function (GetEndTime)
                            )
                    ) 
        THEN 1 --TIME PERIOD ALREADY USED
        ELSE 0 --TIME PERIOD NOT USED
        END;
```

Note: this is just a start script and there are some notes where I think you need to add some additional functionality.
    Also, you would want to turn this into a stored procedure as I mentioned earlier and create two helper functions to handle the splitting and conversion to time as I can see you will need this other places.
    I didn't use between because as you stated the actual time taken is between the 'time_showed' (...time between 17:02 and 17:06 is taken (17:03-17:05)... ). 'BETWEEN' will match to '08:00 - 08:05' and '08:05 - 09:45'.